# Hystrix Dashboard metrics getting reset

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

I am very new to Hystrix and Turbine.
I have to read the metrics of all my services from Hystrix dashboard, for that i have added maven dependencies and @EnableHystrixDashboard on service class, able to read the metrics but the metrics are getting reset for every 10 sec which is useless for my client, i want to increase the timeout interval, for that i did configuration like this in my yml file

```
hystrix
  metrics:
      rollingStats:
        timeInMilliseconds: 50000000
```

but it is not working. Could please help me here to fix the issue.

```
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { JmxAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ProxyApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(ProxyApplication.class,args);
    }
}
```

[Used Dependencies]